# Font-face imported font makes special characters look ugly

Tags: css, special-characters, font-face

i am currently building a website which i am using a custom font for. The font is not avaible @ google webfonts, so i had to download the font and load it through @fontface.

I used the markup from the examples from the site where i downloaded the font.
Link to the font - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Colaborate

heres the css markup

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ColaborateRegular';
src: url('ColabReg-webfont.eot');
src: url('ColabReg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('ColabReg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('ColabReg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('ColabReg-webfont.svg#ColaborateRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

The font works fine on the webpage , but to get to the problem.
I need to use swedish special characters Å Ä Ö - and they just get super weird on the webpage.

heres a image
http://oi44.tinypic.com/2r4tmo0.jpg

What could possibly be the problem? In the photoshop i've recieved from the designer they all look allright with the font.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special characters aren't the characters of the font Colaborate, they are from the fallback font I suppose.

You  need to make sure the package from fontsquirrel contains those special chars.

Comment: Oh... ok, that explains it : /
Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I see that your font set doesn't include those special chars and for this the browser uses your default font family. You should pick a set that supports them.